# I want to click on an html link and echo it in php

Tags: php, html

I cant get it work. Need something really simple, not complicated. And of course not using form and button.

I have a link:

```
<a href="index.php?name=bob&email=me@ymail.com">click here</a>
```

my php script has something like:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['name'];
    echo $_POST['email'];
?>
```

Ok. So how can I post variables using post in an href? Is it possible?

Comment: It's `$_GET['name']`. Those are `GET` parameters not `POST`. `POST` are the ones passed through your HTML input tags

Comment: No it is not possible. You need a `<form>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables added to the Query string are found in `$_GET`, not in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use $_GET['field_name']

```
<?php
echo $_GET['name'];
echo $_GET['email'];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$_POST` is populated from POST request body data. You don't have a POST request here.
`$_GET` is populated from URL query parameters. You *have* URL query parameters here.

```
echo $_GET['name'];
echo $_GET['email'];
```

Answer (score -3):

W3Schools has an example like this (http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_forms.asp):

```
<?php echo $_POST["name"] ?>

<?php echo $_GET["name"] ?>
```

Comment: 1) Please post the essentials of your answer *here*, links tend to die over time. 2) http://w3fools.com